# Replace a word in list and append to same list

Tags: python, list

My List:

```
city=['Venango Municiplaity', 'Waterford ship','New York']
```

Expected Result:

```
city = ['Venango Municiplaity ', 'Waterford ship','New York','Venango','Waterford']
```

Common_words:

```
common_words = ['ship','municipality']
```

Scan all the items in My List and strip the common words and re-insert in the same list as shown in Expected Result.

I'm able to search the items which contains the common words but not sure how to replace that with blank and re-insert in My List.

My code so far:

```
for item in city:
    if(any(x in s.lower() for s in item.split(' ') for x in common_words)) :
```

Comment: ... why are you splitting `item` and using `x in s.lower()` for each part of `item`? Provided that elements in `common_words` do not contain a space you can simply do `if any(x in item.lower() for x in common_words)`. In this case maybe using regexes is simpler... you just need to do a `replaced = re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape, common_words)), item, flags=re.I) if replaced != item: city.append(replaced)`.

Comment: Btw... did you mean to misspell "Municipality" in `city`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have made a small code that works as expected:

```
city=['Venango Municiplaity', 'Waterford ship','New York']
comwo = ['ship','municipality']
for i, c in enumerate(city):
    for ii in comwo:
        if ii in c:
            city.append(city[i].replace(ii,""))
print(city)
```

Output:

```
['Venango Municiplaity', 'Waterford ship', 'New York', 'Waterford ']
```

#### Note:

The list you have made contains incorrect spelling.
Look at list `city`'s first element `Venango`**`Municiplaity`** and second element of common_words **`municipality`**

#### If you want this in one-liner:

```
[city.append(city[i].replace(ii,"")) for ii in comwo for i, c in enumerate(city) if ii in c]
```

I used list comprehension to append to the list `city`.

---

## Edit:

So if you also want to replace the space (if any) behind the word then I have made a separate code:

```
city=['Village home', 'Villagehome','New York']
comwo = ['home']
for i, c in enumerate(city):
    for ii in comwo:
        if ii in c:
            city.append(city[i].replace(" "+ii,"")) if city[i].replace(" "+ii,"") != city[i] else city.append(city[i].replace(ii,""))
print(city)
```

Output:

```
['Village home', 'Villagehome', 'New York', 'Village', 'Village']
```

If you need this in one-liner as well:

```
[city.append(city[i].replace(" "+ii,"")) if city[i].replace(" "+ii,"") != city[i] else city.append(city[i].replace(ii,"")) for ii in comwo for i, c in enumerate(city) if ii in c]
```

Comment: @min2bro it replaces the words within the words as well, for example : Villageship to village. And it does not strip trailing whitespaces. And it is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you the following solution, using `re.sub` with `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to strip the common words ignoring the case:

```
import re

city = ['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship','New York']
common_words = ['ship','municipality']

toAppend = []

for c in city:
    for cw in common_words:
        if cw.lower() in c.lower().split():
            toAppend.append(re.sub(cw, "", c, flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip())

city += toAppend

print(city) # ['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship', 'New York', 'Venango', 'Waterford']
```

And here is the **ONE-LINE STYLE** solution using list comprehension, short but a bit less readable:

```
import re

city = ['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship','New York']
common_words = ['ship','municipality']

city += [re.sub(cw, "", c, flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip() for c in city for cw in common_words if cw.lower() in c.lower().split()]

print(city) # ['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship', 'New York', 'Venango', 'Waterford']
```

Comment: it replace the words within the words as well, for example : Villageship to village

Comment: @min2bro then change `if cw.lower() in c.lower():` to `if cw.lower() in map(lambda x: x.lower(), c.split()):` [Take a look](https://repl.it/repls/DryDecisiveLicense)

Comment: You're right ! I have updated my answer with `if cw.lower() in c.lower().split()` instead of `if cw.lower() in c.lower()`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You can try it, create new list to save there data should be added to your original list, and then concatenate result:

```
In [1]: city=['Venango Municiplaity', 'Waterford ship','New York']

In [2]: common_words = ['ship', 'municiplaity']

In [3]: list_add = []

In [4]: for item in city:
   ...:     item_words = [s.lower() for s in item.split(' ')]
   ...:     if set(common_words) & set(item_words):
   ...:         new_item = [s for s in item.split(' ') if s.lower() not in common_words]
   ...:         list_add.append(" ".join(new_item))
   ...:         

In [5]: city + list_add
Out[5]: ['Venango Municiplaity', 'Waterford ship', 'New York', 'Venango', 'Waterford']
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one approach using Regex.

**Demo:**

```
import re

city=['Venango Municiplaity', 'Waterford ship','New York']
common_words = ['ship','municiplaity']
common_words = "(" + "|".join(common_words) + ")"

res = []
for i in city:
    if re.search(common_words, i, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        res.append(i.strip().split()[0])
print(city + res)
```

**Output:**

```
['Venango Municiplaity', 'Waterford ship', 'New York', 'Venango', 'Waterford']
```

Comment: You should `map(re.escape, common_words)` to handle words containing "special characters".

Comment: if there is an item villageship, it re-inserts it, I just wanted to replace a word in the city.

Comment: part `i.strip().split()[0]` is what I am not a fan of.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a *list comprehension* in order to detect if an item contains something to add to the `city` list.

```
city=['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship','New York']

common_words = ['ship','municipality']
items_to_add = []
for item in city: 
  toAddition = [word for word in item.split() if word.lower() not in common_words]
  if ' '.join(toAddition) != item:
    items_to_add.append(' '.join(toAddition))

print(city + items_to_add)
```

Output

```
['Venango municipality', 'Waterford ship', 'New York', 'Venango', 'Waterford']
```

Comment: fiddling with the initial list changes the problem a bit in this case. having `municipality` instead of `municipality` makes it considerably easier.

Answer (score 4):

Put results in separate list and then use [`list.extend()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.list.extend) to append contents of result list to original list

```
cities = ['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship', 'New York']

common_words = ['ship', 'municipality']

add_list = []

for city in cities:
    rl = []
    triggered = False
    for city_word in city.split():
        if city_word.lower() in common_words:
            triggered = True
        else:
            rl.append(city_word)
    if triggered:
        add_list.append(' '.join(rl))

cities.extend(add_list)
print(cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach with re module:

```
import re

city=['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship','New York']
common_words = ['ship','municipality']
print(city)

for item in city:
    word_list = str(item).split(" ")
    for word in word_list:
        if word.lower() in common_words:
            word_list.remove(word)
            city.extend(word_list)
            continue

print(city)
```

**output:**

```
['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship', 'New York', 'Venango', 'Waterford']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using `extend`:

```
city.extend([i.split()[0] for i in city if i.split()[1].lower() in map(str.lower,common_words)])
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> city=['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship','New York']
>>> common_words = ['ship','municipality']
>>> city.extend([i.split()[0] for i in city if i.split()[1].lower() in map(str.lower,common_words)])
>>> city
['Venango Municipality', 'Waterford ship', 'New York', 'Venango', 'Waterford']
>>>
```

If meant to misspell:

```
>>> city=['Venango Municiplaity', 'Waterford ship','New York']
>>> common_words = ['ship','municipality']
>>> from difflib import SequenceMatcher
>>> city.extend([i.split()[0] for i in city if any(SequenceMatcher(None,i.split()[1].lower(),v).ratio()>0.8 for v in map(str.lower,common_words))])
>>> city
['Venango Municiplaity', 'Waterford ship', 'New York', 'Venango', 'Waterford']
>>>
```